# Is now Linux Mint fully supported on Lenovo G50-80?

Tags: linux, compatibility, wifi-driver

Here is the computer I'd like to buy:
    Lenovo g50-80
    I5 5200U 
    AMD Radeon m5 330

I've no idea on what kind of WiFi chipset it has.

Here someone has not find the driver for WiFi : http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2278975

Now my question is: after 6 month has someone solved the problem? 
Shouldn't I buy this laptop if I want also to surf the Internet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go so far as to say it's not fully supported.

Looking at the bug tracker [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1436940), specifically comment #117, it would appear there is a workaround to get it to function properly.

> Instruction
>
> 1. Disable uefi in bios https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwOE0eOE-p4OMGg4TkxHV0Z3WVk and
>    reinstall os :)
> 2. After running this command "modinfo ath10k_pci | grep 0041" you see this line "alias: pci:v0000168Cd00000041sv*sd*bc*sc*i*" it's okay you
>    kernel support wireless otherway go
>    http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/ath10k/backports/ execute
>    instruction step by step.
>
> https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwOE0eOE-p4OR3N1WWh5MV9vN2s In my
> case i can see load kernel with compat-drivers
>
> https://askubuntu.com/questions/607707/ath10k-installation/607982#answer-607982
>
> 3. Install firmware
>
> git clone https://github.com/atondwal/ath10k-firmware.git
>
> sudo cp -r ath10k-firmware/ath10k/ /lib/firmware/
>
> cd
> /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6164
>
> sudo cp -r hw2.1/
> /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/
>
> sudo echo "options ath10k_core
> skip_otp=y" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath10k_core.conf
>
> Reboot

Any OS that requires me to change my UEFI settings and reinstall it isn't fully compatible in my eyes. That said, it looks like it's possible (as of a couple of weeks ago mind you), so it's probably close. Comment 118 indicates this page [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/678145/my-wifi-qualcomm-atheros-device-168c0041-rev-20-doesnt-show-up-and-work-in/678244#678244) has some useful information too, but none of it sounds solid really.

If it's a laptop you particularly want though you could always use a USB adapter or a different wireless card, at least until it's properly supported.

Comment: BTW I've also a WiFi module of an old Samsung NP300E5C, do you think it's possible to mount that module? To substitute the WiFi module some particular items or cable are needed?

Comment: Depends on the technology. Newer cards are likely to be mini PCI-e, older cards are probably mini PCI. Antenna cables haven't changed though. See [here](http://www.laptopparts101.com/wireless-card/), if your old card is mini PCI-e then you will likely be able to.

Comment: I've a mini PCI-E Here's the model: https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Atheros_AR5B225 so it should be compatible?

Comment: @Timmy Sounds like a better option than the stock one, yes.

Comment: Do you think that replacing the WiFi hardware will void the warranty? I've found this link of disassembly https://youtu.be/bb0w7-1HgvY seems that the WiFi is easily removable, what do you think? Naturally in case of problems I would reassemble the original pieces.

Comment: @Timmy If you have a warranty issue, put their card back in. It looks easy enough, yes. I don't envisage a problem there.

Comment: Of course, you were really helpful!